# Symfony2: class MapClassLoader not found

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to use `MapClassLoader` in `autoload.php` but for some reason I keep getting errors saying

```
Class 'Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\MapClassLoader' not found in ...\autoload.php
```

autoload.php:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\MapClassLoader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    //some values
));

$mapLoader = new MapClassLoader(array(
    //some values
));

$mapLoader->register();
```

I double checked and `MapClassLoader.php` **does** exist in `Symfony\Component\ClassLoader`

Any idea why is it happening? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

autoload.php is a file that configures autoloading for classes so autoloading isn't available in it and you need to include any files manually:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/ClassLoader/MapClassLoader.php';
```

Why is `UniversalClassLoader` available without `require`? Because symfony uses [bootstrap](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/performance.html#use-bootstrap-files) file for system files to reduce file loading overhead.